# Abrir seccion de accordion de bootstrap con link anclado

Tags: bootstrap, accordion

el problema que tengo es que quiero ir de mi página de inicio al darle clic a un link me direccione a mi pagina de preguntas frecuentes y abra una sección de mi accordion. Intente de la forma normal agregando el link#collapse1 pero no funciona de esa manera.

Estos son los links a mi pagina de ayuda/preguntas frecuentes

```
<li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/paginas/preguntasfrecuentes.aspx")%>">Métodos de pago</a></li>
<li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/ayuda")%>">Envios</a></li>
```

Y asi es como tengo mi accordion

```
<div class="panel-group" id="QA-accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#QA-accordion" href="#collapse1">¿Cuál es el procedimiento para darme de alta?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class ="panel-body">
                <p>
                   Ingresar a la página, en la parte inferior hay 3 columnas, bien en la columna de usuarios, en la pestaña de iniciar sesión de click, proporcionar su dirección de e-mail y crear una contraseña y llenar los campos requeridos...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre como realizarlo ya (suena tonto que me responda a mi misma, pero se que algún día alguien ocupara de esto)

Basto con agregar:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    $(anchor).collapse('toggle');
});
</script>
```

Y en los links `href="<%=ResolveUrl("linkdelapagina#id-de-la-seccion-que-deseaba-abrir")%>"`

Comment: Itzy V..yo quiero hacer esto también, pero dime donde agregaste ese codigo??

Answer (score 0):

Si siempre es el mismo panel el que quieres abrir, porque no lo dejas abierto ya poniéndole la clase `in`?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="QA-accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#QA-accordion" href="#collapse1">¿Cuál es el procedimiento para darme de alta?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class ="panel-body">
                <p>
                   Ingresar a la página, en la parte inferior hay 3 columnas, bien en la columna de usuarios, en la pestaña de iniciar sesión de click, proporcionar su dirección de e-mail y crear una contraseña y llenar los campos requeridos...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Saludos

Comment: No es lo que ocupo en si, pero ya encontre la solución, gracias

Comment: En ese caso, podrías responderte a ti mismo para que la comunidad se beneficie de la solución ;)